# First value as the key in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array( 'id' => 1, 'animal' => 'dog', 'color' => 'red' ),
    1 => array( 'id' => 12, 'animal' => 'cat', 'color' => 'green' ),
    2 => array( 'id' => 37, 'animal' => 'lion', 'color' => 'blue' ),
);
```

and I want this output:

```
$arr = array(
    1 => array( 'animal' => 'dog', 'color' => 'red' ),
    12 => array( 'animal' => 'cat', 'color' => 'green' ),
    37 => array( 'animal' => 'lion', 'color' => 'blue' ),
);
```

Any good idea instead of using php loops, etc ?
Any functions? like `array_values` or `array_combine`

=================
**Possible solution**

```
$new = array();
foreach( $arr as $item ){
    $id = array_shift( $item );
    $new[$id] = $item;
}
```

Comment: You're modifying an array. You're going to use a loop even if it's in a function call.

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to defend your aversion to using "PHP loops" and explain (in more detail) what you'd want to accomplish instead.

Comment: I think because the `id` is arbitrary, so there isn't going to be a function to do this.  Everyone's brain just goes straight to the obvious...oh let's loop through that sucker!  Then you're like...no loops please....and we're all like ...no.

Comment: You still haven't explained WHY you don't want to use loops. The consensus seems to be that this is the right time to use a loop, hence the downvotes.

Comment: @Dagon please have a look at @AbraCadaver 's answer to know what is left. php function `array_column`!

Comment: @Arash it still actually uses loops (sure you don't see them- but so what), so i dont get it, no matter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requires PHP >= 5.5.0 and the `id` will still be in the nested arrays:

```
$result = array_column($arr, null, 'id');
```

Answer (score 2):

One can define a new array and loop through the main array, using `array_shift` to pop first element (the id field) and then make the remaining part, value for that index in new array:

```
$new = array();
foreach( $arr as $item ){
    $id = array_shift( $item );
    $new[$id] = $item;
}
```